# Exploring nutch over hadoop

Tags: hadoop, nutch

What possibly can i do with Hadoop and Nutch used as a search engine ? I know that nutch is used to build a web crawler . But i'm not finding the perfect picture . Can i use mapreduce with nutch and do some mapreduce job ? Any ideas are welcome . Few links will be greatly appreciated . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only do Map/Reduce jobs you don't need Nutch but Hadoop only.  Hadoop brings you a cluster file system and a scheduler for map/reduce jobs on the filesystem.

As Nutch builds on top of Hadoop you can create your own map/reduce jobs on Nutch data as long as you understand the data structure and what the crawler is doing.

However if you only wanted to run some map/reduce jobs, just install hadoop and off you go.

Comment: You can use solr for the search portion of the search engine. Nutch includes jobs for indexing content into solr. [Nutch / Solr integration tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial)